# How to display ArrayList items in a JComponent

Tags: java, search, arraylist, io, jcomponent

I have this:

```
ArrayList lovely = new ArryList(4);
lovely.add("Tall, Short, Average");         // line 1
lovely.add("mangoes, apples, Bananas");     // line 2
lovely.add("this, that");                   // line 3
lovely.add(“1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6”)              // line 4
```

I'd like to have the array list displayed in such a way that each category shows in its own line, like how google list their search results. Does anyone know how to do this? I'd like such displayed in a JComponent, but am not sure of which one to use, nor how to do this. Do JAVA programmers use JTextFields , JTextPanes, or what do they use.

Help here will be much appreciated.

Comment: Unrealted to the question, but, Use `ArrayList<String> lovely = new ArryList<String>(4);` or better `List<String> lovely = new ArryList<String>(4);`

Answer (score 1):

Java programmers use a `JList`. You can constuct it like this:

```
new JList(lovely.toArray())
```

It displays each item in a separate line in a list.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try [JLabel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JLabel.html) or [JTextPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextPane.html) because they support simple HTML commands.  It's quite nice if you want to give neat output in a simple manner.  Have a look here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/html.html